# The password don't work after creating user

Tags: wordpress

I am making custom form of registration & authorization. I fill fields on the page of registration user. But after on authorization page It's display that I entered incorrect password. What can I do in this situation?
Form of registration:

```
<form  id="form_id" method="post">
<div >Enter login :</div>
<input id="name" type="text"  name="name"/>

<div>Email  : </div>
<input type="email" id="email" name="email"/>

<div >Enter password1 :</div>
<input id="password1" type="password"  name="password1"/>

<div >Enter password2 :</div>
<input id="password2" type="password"  name="password2"/>

<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

functions.php:

```
function ab_create_new_user() {
$userdata = array (
    'user_pass'  => $_POST['password1'],
    'user_email' => $_POST['email'],
    'user_login' => $_POST['name'],
);
$user_id = wp_insert_user($userdata);
if( ! is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
    echo'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
exit();
}
```

Form of authorization:

```
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/wp-login.php" method="post">
<label>Email: <br />
    <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" /></label>
<label>Password :<br />
    <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" /></label>
<label><input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" /> Запомнить меня</label>
<input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" value="Войти" />
</form>
```

Comment: Simple question:) You didn`t check mathing passwords. Are you sure that your passwords are matching each other? Are you excluded typo error?

Comment: And where placing your form? On front-end part of site?

Comment: @Maxim Sarandi, in front. I enter pass 123 in registration page and 123 in authorization page. But I don't enter

Comment: Silly question: Is the user actually created in the `wp_user` table in your database?

Comment: @cale_b, Yes, user is in the table wp_user and pass is hashed.

Comment: That's a huge datapoint.  So, that means the problem lies in the attempt to login.  I'm guessing the form is either missing something important, or fields are not named properly.  You might check out the function [wp_login_form](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form) - it may give you insights into what's missing / wrong with the form in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For login users on Front-end you must use [wp_signon()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_signon/)

Or [wp_authenticate()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_authenticate/)

Create form, send on admin-post.php and create hook where you will signon users and redirect where you’re need. Or use default WordPress login page. Without custom form.

Comment: It is possible to post the form to `wp-login.php` as OP is doing, and make it work.  Something else is failing.

Comment: Check all parameters from wp-login form. Default form. Open developer tools in browser. Check Network tab and send valid form in your dashboard. See all parameters which needed to success login

Comment: @Maxim Sarandi, What can I do it ?